# How do I get a `solid` to render over a `sprite` in DragonRuby Game Toolkit?

Tags: dragonruby-game-toolkit

The following code renders a `sprite` and a `solid` with an alpha. But the `solid` renders below the `sprite`. How do I get the solid to render above the `sprite`?

```rb
def tick args
  args.outputs.sprites << { 
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    w: 50,
    h: 60,
    path: 'sprites/square-red.png'
  }

  args.outputs.solids << {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    w: 1280,
    h: 720,
    r: 80,
    g: 80,
    b: 80,
    a: 128
  }
end
```

Answer (score 3):

The default render order (bottommost to topmost) for primitives is:

- `solids`
- `sprites`
- `primitives`
- `labels`
- `lines`
- `borders`

To have a `solid` render over a `sprite`, you must use `args.outputs.primitives` which will render in the order that you add to the collection (regardless of primitive type):

```rb
def tick args
  # step 1: use .primitives instead of .sprites
  args.outputs.primitives << { 
    x: 100, 
    y: 100, 
    w: 50, 
    h: 60, 
    path: 'sprites/square-red.png' 
  }.sprite # step 2: invoke the .sprite function on the primitive

  # step 3: use .primitives instead of .solids
  args.outputs.primitives << { 
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    w: 1280,
    h: 720,
    r: 80,
    g: 80,
    b: 80,
    a: 128
  }.solids # step 4: mark the primitive as a solid
end
```

This begs the question:

> Should I use `.primitives` for everything?

That is totally fine to do frankly.